# New to C, need help in understanding below function

Tags: c, linux

```
case 1:
    if (fork())
        wait(0);
    else
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)NULL);
    break;
```

I had been told to make a user interface Textual display Menu in C that was previously made with the help of a Shell script. I have gone through the ncurses library but if some one can direct me to code that was previously implemented using ncurses for a menu in C for Linux, I would be grateful.

Comment: This is two questions in one. The first is about how fork works, the second about ncurses, you should split them up.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're showing is just a snippet, it's not a "function". It looks to be copied out of the middle of a `switch` statement.

If the value of the expression being switched upon is 1, it will `fork()` a new process. The child process will then `execlp()` and run the `ls` program. The parent will wait for the child to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The secret then, is in fork.

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned to the parent, and 0 is returned to the child. On failure, -1 is returned to the parent and no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

When you fork you get another process, running exactly as the first one is. The only difference is that in the child process fork has returned a different value.

Your code is basically saying:

If I'm the parent, wait around.

If I'm the child, do work - in your case get a directory listing.

Once the directory listing is done I'm assuming the child dies and the parent goes back on with its life.

This is fairly typical code for doing what you're doing. You have a main application that is the "menu" and you're spawning off temporary copies of yourself just executing the shell command needed by the menu before returning to life as normal.

Check out `man fork`... [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

Answer (score 0):

About the code:

```
case 1:
    if (fork())
        wait(0);
    else
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)NULL);
    break;
```

`fork()` creates a new process, an exact copy. Fork return the PID of the child process to the parent (so it will execute `wait(0)`) and `0` to the child process (so it will execute the `execlp()`).

With `execlp()` your are mutating the process (indicating the executable and the arguments). You should consult the corresponding `man pages`:

- [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)
- [execlp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)